# Postgres statement_timeout with No results were returned by the query

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a query that I'm trying to execute via a PreparedStatement:

`SET local statement_timeout TO 10000 ; SELECT 'x', pg_sleep(5);`

When I run this via PGAdmin, the query will execute and there are no issues.

When I run this via a PreparedStatement in JDBC I get: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.`

Anyone have an idea how to resolve this or if I am doing something incorrectly?

Comment: I would not except it to work in either case as `DUAL` is an Oracle thing. Or are you using EDB Advanced Server with the Oracle layer? If so that is the sort of information you need to share as it is a fork of Postgres and not really covered by the `postgresql` tag.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I just did a quick edit of the question. The query is actually: 

SET local statement_timeout TO 10000 ; SELECT 'x', pg_sleep(5);

I am using edb advanced server

Comment: I get this: `WARNING:  SET LOCAL can only be used in transaction blocks` when I run in `psql` in autocommit mode. Is that maybe what is happening in `JDBC`  case? I would look in the Postgres log to see what it says.

Comment: That is not one statement, that is two statements.